# Log messages are not written in the log file

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I have configured a project with Log4j. I have configured log4j using `log4.properties` file.
While the test runs it creates the `myLog.log` file but nothing is written to the log file.
Appender we are using as `RollingFileAppender` and `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG`.

Can any one suggest what might be causing this problem?

Here is log4j.properties for the project.

```
log4j.rootLogger= DEBUG, ConsoleAppender, Rolling 
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 

log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-2p %c.%M(): %m%n 
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=5MB 
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=2 
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=D:\Logs\myProj.log 
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4p %c.%M(): %m%n 
## Following two lines have been removed now.
log4j.logger.com=WARN 
log4j.logger.org=WARN
```

Received Log in the log file :

```
2012-01-16 22:02:08,534 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader(): << content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2012-01-16 22:02:08,534 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader(): << connection: close
2012-01-16 22:02:08,534 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader(): << content-length: 236
2012-01-16 22:02:08,550 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader(): << server: httpd.js
2012-01-16 22:02:08,550 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.receiveResponseHeader(): << date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 03:02:06 GMT
2012-01-16 22:02:08,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "{"name":"clickElement","sessionId":"2fad55cf-670e-44f3-ab60-7d2f76f641e6","status":0,"value":"This action is final and cannot be undone?"}"
2012-01-16 22:02:08,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.shutdown(): Connection shut down
2012-01-16 22:02:08,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.releaseConnection(): Released connection is not reusable.
2012-01-16 22:02:08,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.freeEntry(): Releasing connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
2012-01-16 22:02:08,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.notifyWaitingThread(): Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2012-01-16 22:02:10,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.getConnection(): Get connection: HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055], timeout = 120000
2012-01-16 22:02:10,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(): [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 0, total allocated: 0 out of 2000
2012-01-16 22:02:10,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getFreeEntry(): No free connections [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
2012-01-16 22:02:10,566 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(): Available capacity: 2000 out of 2000 [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]][null]
2012-01-16 22:02:10,581 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.createEntry(): Creating new connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://127.0.0.1:7055]]
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(): Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7055
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(): CookieSpec selected: best-match
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache.process(): Auth cache not set in the context
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.tryExecute(): Attempt 1 to execute request
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.sendRequestHeader(): Sending request: GET /hub/session/2fad55cf-670e-44f3-ab60-7d2f76f641e6/alert_text HTTP/1.1
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): >> "GET /hub/session/2fad55cf-670e-44f3-ab60-7d2f76f641e6/alert_text HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): >> "Accept: application/json, image/png[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): >> "Host: 127.0.0.1:7055[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): >> "[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.sendRequestHeader(): >> GET /hub/session/2fad55cf-670e-44f3-ab60-7d2f76f641e6/alert_text HTTP/1.1
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.sendRequestHeader(): >> Accept: application/json, image/png
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.sendRequestHeader(): >> Host: 127.0.0.1:7055
2012-01-16 22:02:10,597 DEBUG org.apache.http.headers.sendRequestHeader(): >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "connection: close[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "content-length: 236[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "server: httpd.js[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 03:02:10 GMT[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.wire.wire(): << "[\r][\n]"
2012-01-16 22:02:10,612 DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(): Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Show the full contents of your `log4j.properties`

Comment: Where is the properties file and your Java logging code?

Comment: can you show us the code? and also the logger file if you may. Maybe the logger's class is missing in the log4j.properties file.

Comment: log4j.properties is kept in src folder.

Comment: @PriWeb Then bring it up and paste its contents here

Comment: Thanks for overwhelming response. I hope to find the solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or more detailed: No logging-request from com or org-packages with log-level < WARN will be enabled. So it wont be forwarded to your rootLogger.

Quote:

> A log request of level p in a logger with (either assigned or inherited, whichever is 
>   appropriate) level q, is enabled if p >= q.

and

> Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to all the appenders in 
>   that logger as well as the appenders higher in the hierarchy.

See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: Thanks it helps.But when I see the log none of the statements are from my java classes. All the logs statements are related to other packages. I am pasting some porition of log in the question.After that I have added log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR. Now I am not seeing any thing in my log. I don't know why none of the line from my java class is getting logged in the log file.

Comment: @PriWeb - Whats the fully qualified name of the class in which you are using the logger? Paste how you are creating the logger and which log-level you are using in your log-statements.

Comment: In addition: You can add "-Dlog4j.debug="true"" to your run-configuration to see how Log4J is configuring itself (is there maybe another log4j.properties on the classpath?)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure your `log4j.properties` is loaded in classpath. I assume that the file can also be found inside the `WEB-INF/classes` directory if it is a webapp. But because you say that the file is getting created, I think that is not a problem.

So, try with this

```
log4j.rootLogger= DEBUG, Console, Rolling 
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 

log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-2p %c.%M(): %m%n 
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=5MB 
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=2 
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=D:\Logs\myProj.log 
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-4p %c.%M(): %m%n
```

**Note that I have removed the last two lines.**

Basically, those lines set the log level to `WARN` to all packages starting with `com` and `org`. So, unless you have any `WARN` messages being logged, you won't see anything at all on the log files.

You can experiment with levels by doing something like

```
log4j.logger.com.foo.bar=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.foo.bar.MyClass=TRACE
```

The above will print log all `com.foo.bar` logs in `DEBUG` whereas will print `com.foo.bar.MyClass` logs in the `TRACE` level.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful. But when I see the log none of the statements are from my java classes. All the logs statements are related to other packages. I am pasting some porition of log in the question.

Comment: @PriWeb can't help but ask, have you logged anything at all in your classes?